# Can someone please find the private key to this bitcoin address?

Tags: private-key

I need help this is URGENT! find the private key and send it to me.

3PbacVZwS2L5i9C2Cmz9rPu8s4qjyYkufk

I really need this to pay for a bill. I have a deadline and have been trying to figure it out but cant. PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: this is probably a hoax, there are roughly 50 bitcoin on the address, and it is highly suspicious to have such a request of "ownership" from a new member in the forum. Also the address shows more than 150 bitcoins going in and out only in February... This is nearly one million (EUROs, USD, CHF, ...) if this is for real, you don't need the help from a public forum. This would require specialists in analyzing your PC, the surrounding security model, and if not in place, the mental health. (and yes, I am aware that this comment qualifies for a downvote)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to recover private key?,](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84215/i-need-to-recover-private-key)

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to work backwards from a bitcoin address to the private key, sorry. If this was possible, the bitcoin system would be incredibly broken.

You will need to find the wallet software that generated this address, or a backup of the keypair / mnemonic seed phrase for that wallet, otherwise you will not be able to recover the private key and spend those funds.

Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I want to clarify that it seems you may not be familiar with what a private key is. Secondly, this address is associated with the XAPO Wallet (https://oxt.me/address/3PbacVZwS2L5i9C2Cmz9rPu8s4qjyYkufk).

A private key is a cryptographic key used to sign transactions and prove ownership of a Bitcoin address. It should be kept confidential because anyone with access to the private key has control over the associated funds.

XAPO was a Bitcoin wallet and vault service designed to offer secure storage and convenient management of Bitcoin. However, XAPO underwent changes, and its services were acquired by Coinbase.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [vanitygen-plus](https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus) for the underlying address to find private keys but, it will take an inordinately long amount of time. If your bill is urgent you shouldn't bother.

The rule with Bitcoin is it is up to you to keep your wallet secure, the same as a wallet is in your pocket nobody can open it unless you take it out and give it to someone. Bitcoin cannot be responsible for your computer security and cannot adjudicate as to the owner. The Bitcoin in your wallet belongs to anyone who has the password that can allow the signing of a transaction with the cryptographic signature proving ownership of the bitcoin. That way there will not be theft and it keeps Bitcoin matters from tying up the court.

The same there is pay and then pay. When you receive a pay envelope the pay is made up in the office to be your pay, but when it is in the envelope your pay is not received, at least if the standard is it must be able to be spent on something that is available because you have the money then it is not paid at least until it is received and counted. Then you are paid. The same with a Bitcoin transaction, a transaction is paid to make the transaction from the utxo but the recipient is not paid until they can sign for a transaction to spend the Bitcoin, so receiving notification of a transaction is not secure and you cannot spend until your transaction is included in a block that is an indelible part of the blockchain to prevent unspending after somebody supposes to receive. You pay the transaction and say that it is paid (with Bitcoin) but ultimately it is not paid until the bitcoin can be spent.

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is specific and accurate. It is useful to understand how long an inordinately long amount of time is perhaps, an amount of time without ordinals?